# arara keeps asking me to upgrade my Mac Java?

Tags: arara, mac

I have been using `arara + TeXShop` to automate the `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex`, until recently, `array` pops up a window, asking me to upgrade my Mac Java.

[image]

Then, I did. I clicked "More Info", which led me to [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp).

However, it is still not working after I upgraded my Java. How may I fix it?

Comment: Hi there! I'll take a look right now. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Awesome! Thanks a lot for helping out! Do please let me know if you need more information/experiments. I will be around.

Comment: My tests are done, let's go for the reports: I have tried a sample document with TeXShop 3.48 + `arara` 3.0 in Yosemite 10.10.1 + Java 1.8.0, and everything worked just fine. I got a similar prompt the other day when I installed Minecraft (a game) in my Mac because IIRC it requires a legacy Java 6.0 install regardless of any other JVM's in your systems (apparently Yosemite gets confused and don't act properly on this subject). So, I suggest that, in addition to the latest Java installed (I think you installed 1.8.0), install this one as well: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: Just another note: thankfully I'm quite feral with versions, so `arara` works with every version of Java so far, starting from Java 5.0, so either Java 6 or Java 8 represents no threat to `arara`. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda You are awesome, man! Installing the one you suggested does the trick! The awesome `arara` is back in town again! Thank you so much for the help again and, of course, for your creating the awesome `arara`! Merry Christmas! `:-D`

Comment: yay, I'm glad the procedure worked! Would you mind if I convert my comment to a proper answer, so we can mark this question as solved? By the way, stay tuned, the upcoming `arara` 4.0 will hit CTAN and TeX Live in the next months. `:)` And Merry Christmas to you too! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Not at all! I would definitely be more than happy to accept your answer after you convert it! Awesome, looking forward to seeing `arara` 4.0!

Comment: Thanks, I'll write an answer. `:)` Here you go, a preview: https://vimeo.com/113328301

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>From my comment to a proper answer. `:)`</sub>

I have tried a sample document with TeXShop 3.48 + `arara` 3.0 in Yosemite 10.10.1 + Java 1.8.0, and everything worked just fine.

That said, I got a similar prompt the other day when I installed Minecraft in my Mac because IIRC it requires a legacy Java 6.0 install regardless of any other JVM's in your systems — the word in the street says that, apparently, Yosemite gets confused and don't act properly on this subject.

A possible workaround is to install [this DMG package](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) containing a legacy Java 6.0 virtual machine available from Apple, in addition to the latest Java installed (at the time of this writing, Java 8.0). That way, Yosemite will at least understand there's a JVM available and will complain no more. `:)`

It's worth noting that `arara` works with all versions, starting from Java 5.0, and with the majority of VM vendors (like OpenJDK), so no matter if it's being invoked with either Java 6.0 or Java 8.0, `arara` will remain pristine. `:)`